# EGIT doesn't create the master branch

Tags: git, egit, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to use **Egit** with **Spring tool suite**.
These are the steps I performed:

1. I created a new project on Spring tool suite
2. Right click on the project and then **team->shared project**
3. I created a new git repository with the name of the project (ProgettoJava)
   [image]

As you can see from the next pic, I have no **master**. Shouldn't Git create a Master branch?
[image]

What's my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git, a branch name like `master` holds the commit hash ID of the *tip* of the branch.  (The hash ID is the unique identifier that specifies that one particular commit.  No other commit will ever have the same hash ID.)

Hence the name `master` always holds the ID of some existing, valid commit.

**A new, empty repository has no commits in it.**  Here's the list of all the valid commit IDs in a new, empty repository: ().  Which of these commit IDs should `master` have in it?

Until you make your first commit, *there are no valid commit IDs*, so there cannot be a `master` branch.  Make your first commit while you're on branch `master` and branch `master` will appear out of nowhere.  Now that there's precisely *one* comit in the repository, `master` will contain its ID (whatever ID that is—they appear to be quite random, though actually they're a cryptographic checksum of everything that went into the commit).

When you make your *second* commit, `master` will hold that new commit's ID.  The first commit's ID will be inside the second commit, so that Git can start at the end—the second commit—and work backwards.  That's all a branch name is: it holds the ID of the *last* commit, from which Git works backwards to earlier commits.

Once you have some commits, you can have as many branch names as you like.  (If you have one commit and many branch names, all the names point to that one commit, since that's the only commit.  That's normal for Git!)  Until then, though, you cannot have any branch names—and yet, you're still *on* some branch.  The (nonexistent) branch that you're on, normally `master`, will be created by creating the first commit.